# Why can I compare an enum with null?

Tags: c#

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types), I can compare value types with null, by marking them nullable. This is particularly useful when using null-propagation in nested objects.

However, when comparing specific enums, which I thought were value-types, I can still compare with null, like this:

```
public class NullColorComparer
{

    public bool CompareNullWithColor()
    {
        // This return false.
        return null == Color.Red;
    }
}

public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue
}
```

Why does this work? Shouldn't compilation fail with a type error?

Comment: Your code produces `warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'Color' is never equal to 'null' of type 'Color?'` for me. That sums it up quite good I think.

Comment: Assignment is not possible being value type or when explicitly marked as Nullable enum, but you are doing comparison not assignment

Comment: Btw, that's not enum specific:  `int ten = 10;
    if (null == ten)
    {
    }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enum is casted to a nullable version of it before comparison, so it can and will evaluate. The result is however always the same.

That is why the compiler warns you:

> Warning CS0472 The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'Color' is never equal to 'null' of type 'Color?'

Although the comparison is useless, the compiler doesn't prevent you to perform it. Just like it doesn't prevent your to make a `if(false) { }`, which is just as useless.

Comment: Just a side note: Back in the days of vb6, `if false then...end if` was the only way to create a multi line pseudo comment. Back then, it was very useful.

Comment: An interesting observation is that if you paste this line into linqpad: `bool a = null == Color.Red;` you get no warning (using System.Drawing.Color), but with a specific enum in the same linqpad script, you do.

Comment: Definitely strange, i agree.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `Color` is not an enum. It is a struct.

Comment: Ah, so it's a struct mimicking an enum, didn't know about that distinction, and yes, then it makes sense (that is, it makes sense that the two behave differently, not entirely sure it makes sense that I get no warning but that's entirely different).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You get no warning because the colors are properties, so in theory they could return different values on different calls.. The enum on the other hand has constant values and thus the compiler can determine this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, no it's not mimicking an enum, because `Color.Red` would return an object of type `Color`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed A struct. And a struct can't be null.

Comment: @Adrian Not entirely. The colors might be properties, but properties returning a struct. And since structs can't be null, the comparison can never be true. However, they failed to provide a check for that.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The funny thing is it does fail on `Color red = new Color(); var b = red == null;` (in this case it even is an error!)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen only primitive structs (enum, int etc) generate this warning (and `Color` is custom struct). You can read about reasons (basically - backward compatibility) here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18975. There you can also read that using `<Features>strict</Features>` you can make compiler generate this warning for all structs.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes you're right. Actually, you can't even use the `==` operator unless its overloaded in the struct itself... So in theory you could define an operator that compares to a reference type like `static  bool operator == (Object left, MyStruct right)` and then you could compare it with `null`, and have it evaluate to `true`. However, the compiler should know whether such an overload exists (in case of `System.Drawing.Color` it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

The `null` side of your comparison is treated as a `Nullable<Program.Color>` and it will compile, because you can compare a `Nullable<WhatEver>` to a `WhatEver`.

It will however, issue a warning:

> Warning    CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'Program.Color' is never equal to 'null' of type 'Program.Color?'

Comment: So you also missed the `Color` enum in your console application? ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler doesn't prevent comparing. But you get a warning: "The result of the expression is always 'false' since the value of type 'Color' is never equal to 'null' of type 'Color?'".
It lets you compare, but says that it always will be false. This is true for any value type. You can even compare an `Int32` value with null, you will get the same result. No need for compile time error'

Answer (score 0):

Even though a value type can never be `null`, you can still compare value types to `null` and it will always result in `false`.

Some tools like ReSharper can detect that and might actually warn you that it's a useless comparison.

Comment: Note that, as mentioned in other answers, it already generates a warning without Resharper.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that it's actually a compiler warning. That's even better.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, Based on your code you always will get false because you are comparing a static instance of enum with a null value.

Your comparison will be meaningful is some case like this:

```
public enum TestEnum
    {
        Item1,
        Item2
    }
```

...

```
TestEnum? t = null; 
return  t== null;
```

...

Comment: OP knows you get false, just not why it doesn't error out.